# Is there a way to ignore Custom annotation in SpringBoot bean config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am using a dependency JAR in my project which has a custom annotation "@monitor"
This annotation is being used at **a lot of places in the code**.

Going forward, I would like to perform a quick test if there are any performance improvements if we ignore this annotation(As there are reflection api calls due to this).

I do not want to remove annotation classes from the dependency JAR as other projects might be using this. I also do not want to go to every method in my code or inside JAR to remove the "@monitor" annotation from methods.

Is there a way in SpringBoot2 to ignore a particular annotation from a spring configuration class?

Is there a way in SpringBoot2 to ignore a particular annotation.

Comment: "*I do not want to remove annotation classes from the dependency JAR as other projects might be using this*" Then you can't

Comment: It sounds like you're looking just to _test_ something...  Why not add a second copy of the dependency (in wherever you're pulling the dependencies from) which doesn't contain these.  The other teams can keep using the one which does contain the annotations, and your team can try out the one without them.